# Can I open a file with geany from the terminal

Tags: terminal, geany

I know there is a shortcut to open a file with sublime text from the terminal but id there something similar with geany, the only info I can find online about it is opening a file from geany to the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

If Geany is inside your path, just call `geany <file>`. This should work on every platform, Geany is running.

Out of Geany's man page:

```
SYNOPSIS
       geany [option]  [+number]  [files ...]
```

This will open files either in a new session or, if already a session of Geany is running, inside the existing one.

A file can be given as space separated list and might take even line numbers:

```
files ...
 A space-separated list of filenames.  Absolute  and  relative
 filenames  can be used. Geany also recognises line and column
 information when appended to the filename with  colons,  e.g.
 "geany foo.bar:10:5" will open the file foo.bar and place the
 cursor in line 10 at column 5.
```

Comment: I find that if I use this solution, as opposed to the solution suggested by @Dencker, the Terminal session becomes blocked running geany.  I would have invoke as `geany FILENAME &` to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `open`:

```
open [PATH_TO_FILE] -a [PATH_TO_GEANY_APP]
```

The `a` option defines which application to use.

#### To make this shorter, create an alias:

Something like `echo 'alias geany="open $1 -a [PATH_TO_GEANY_APP]"' >> ~/.bash_profile && chmod u+x ~/.bash_profile`. Then open a new Terminal window and type `geany [path_to_file]`.

Comment: Thankyou, I will look in to this, I know with sublime you only need to be in the directory and then type the file name and something like .s/ to open it in sublime.

Comment: This basically does the same, except you type `geany [filename]`. :)

Comment: This is only valid for Mac OSX. The questioner didn't mention which OS he is using.

Comment: No, but judging on the level of knowledge, I assume he is not using Linux. And based on his use of the word "Terminal", it's probably not Windows.

Comment: Even on MacOS I wouldn't use this -- instead I'd updating $PATH. But this might be taste.